# Calling a PHP login function

Tags: php

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>


<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="controller.php">

<input type = "text" name = "txtUsername" value = "testuser"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "txtPassword" value = "password"><br>

<Input type = 'Submit' Name ='Login' value="Login">

</FORM>

</body>
</html>

<?PHP

    include_once("controller/Controller.php");  

    function login($username,$password) {
            $controller = new Controller();  
            $controller->invoke("testUsername","testPassword");  
    }

?>
```

Can I please have some help to call the PHP login function with the values from the two input boxes?

Comment: Is this file just the `controller.php` ?

Comment: is your controller.php in the same directory? if not, change the path in the action attribute to the true path. also, please give us a hint why you want to include your controller.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
$pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];

login($user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    login($_POST['txtUsername'],$_POST['txtPassword'])
}
```

Of course you need to process the request inside `controller.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to be sure, you can use

```
if (isset($_POST['txtUsername'])&&isset($_POST['txtPassword'])) {
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    login($username, $password);
} else {
    // some logic actions if there no values on txtUsername and txtPassword.
}
```

Also,  I also suggest if you could use a placeholder attribute rather than a value attribute like...

```
<input type="text" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Username"><br>
<input type="password" name="txtPassword"><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
```

also:

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
{
  $user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
  $pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];

  login($user, $pass); 
}
```